# C++ regex validation fails

Tags: c++, regex

I am using a 3rd party C++ package that does a regex validation as its first step. The following is the input string

```
/hls/FOOD_HD/500a/format-hls-track-en-bandwidth-500000-repid-root_audio500-duration-180180-frag-42.ts
```

with the regex expression,

```
.*/(?P<name>.*)/format-(?P<format>[^/]+)-track-(?P<track>[^/]+)-bandwidth-(?P<bitrate>\d+)-repid-(?P<repid>[^/]+)-duration-(?P<duration>\d+)-frag-(?P<frag>\d+).ts
```

and the library seems to reject the string. I have tried a couple of online regex checker and it works. I would like to know if that's the issue with regex expression itself or with the package.

For instance, the following regex / string combo works:

```
regex: .*/(?P<name>.*)/format-(?P<format>[^/]+)-track-(?P<track>[^/]+)-bandwidth-(?P<bitrate>\d+)-repid-(?P<repid>[^/]+)-duration-(?P<duration>\d+)-frag-(?P<frag>\d+)-.*\.ts
string: /hls/FOOD_HD/3000/format-hls-track-muxed-bandwidth-3000000-repid-root_audio_video5-duration-180180-frag-3000-163.ts
```

Comment: what exactly isnt working?

Comment: You cannot use named groups with `std::regex`, use `.*/(.*)/format-([^/]+)-track-([^/]+)-bandwidth-(\d+)-repid-([^/]+)-duration-(\d+)-frag-(\d+)\.ts`

Comment: What is the 3rd party library? **What is the regex flavor?** Note that in some flavors, you should declare the group names as `(?<name>)`. Also, if you mention *validation*, why don't you use anchors, `^` and `$` around the pattern? Show the code please.

Comment: The issue is I do not have access to the code. It's just a compiled binary

Comment: Ok, but what is the regex flavor, is there any way you can check it? Documentation, etc.? Also, make sure you escape the `.` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As of now, I do not have any doc for that library. Trying hard to get the source code though.

Comment: Well, try also a less "heavy" [`.*?/(?P<name>[^/]*)/format-(?P<format>[^/]+)-track-(?P<track>[^/]+)-bandwidth-(?P<bitrate>\d+)-repid-(?P<repid>[^/]+)-duration-(?P<duration>\d+)-frag-(?P<frag>\d+)\.ts`](https://regex101.com/r/LXXPg5/1).

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with the library. Thanks for your help !